# how to clear the dynamically created UITextfield values in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitextfield

I Created five `UITextField` using for loop i want to clear the textfield values when i Click the Clear button but only clear the last textfield values.i want to clear all text fiel values how can i solve this any one Help me Thanks

Comment: you want to clear all textField when user press clear, am I correct ?

Comment: Show us how you create them. I suspect you made the so usual overwrite-pointer-and-make-object-dangling mistake.

Comment: @yuvaraj: check with my answer it'll work

Comment: @MidhunMP:Thanks for Your reply

Comment: @MidhunMP why i am get down vote

Comment: @yuvaraj: i think your question was not clear before editing, and there is no code related to your question. If you add the code of `UITextField` creating loop, it is more easier to find the issue. When you post a issue, make sure that the question is clear and you have aded the code related to your issue. If you want to know more go to http://stackoverflow.com/faq Don't worry someone downvoted me too :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In  your clear method write like:

```
for (UIView *addedView in [self.view subViews])
{
   if([addedView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
      UITextField *myText = (UITextField *)addedView ;
      myText.text = @"";
    }
}
```

Here each sub view is taken from the self.view and check if it is a `UITextField` or not. If it is a `UITextField` then we set `@""` to it.

Comment: yuvaraj has asked for changing the last textfield value..not all the textField's values.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper: please read his question carefully **i want to clear the textfield values when i Click the Clear button but only clear the last textfield values. how can i solve this** . He is asking for clearing the whole textFields not last one

Comment: read: "but only clear the last textfield values" he has not written "but not clear the last textfield values".There is a big difference in both the statements.

Comment: :) lol ok.. this is not about who giving the right answer..this is about the "right answer " :)

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper:please check his question now, he is edited it

Comment: yes now this is his mistake.He should be giving everyone a +1.and i am not going to give answer to any of his questions from now.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) 
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
             [(UITextField*) view setText:@""];
```

Comment: same applies to your answer too.Please read the question fully before actually trying to give an answer like this.

Comment: @yuvaraj please come and explain iPhone Developer your question, because i know im getting it right.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by using following:

```
-(void)loopMethod
{
    lastTextField.tag=100;
}

-(void)buttonClick
{
    UITextField *textField=(UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
    textField.text=NULL;
}
```